# Centering a panel on screen

Tags: basic4android

I've been playing with centering a panel on a device screen. I've tried a few things but cant get the syntax/math correct. I am adding the panel with it's size relative to the screen size as below (80% width and 40% height). At the moment I left the x,y location at 0,0 - Any suggestions on correct syntax to center on screen are appreciated!

```
Activity.AddView(quitsavepnl,0,0, 80%x, 40%y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
Activity.AddView(quitsavepnl, 50%x - 80%x / 2, 50%y - 40%y / 2, 80%x, 40%y)
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it perfectly. I was using something similar I saw in a thread at b4a, but the math was working right.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `DisplayMetrics` to get device screen and add it in the center of device screen if you want it.

Or if you want to display `View` in the center of parent `View` use `CENTER_IN_PARENT`, which is available in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I am developing in Basic4Android.